# How to write in the center (vertically and horizontally) of a blank page

Tags: latex

I am currently producing a scientific report. Then, right after the introduction, I wanted to add a blank page where I put " PART I" in the middle of the page (="PART I" is centered in vertically and horizontally in this blank page). How could I do that?

Comment: To centre text `\mbox{}
\vfill
\centering
text
\vfill
\mbox{}`, but it would probably be better to set up automatic part pages. Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: The following: \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

Comment: Would changing to `report` an option, there part pages work out of the box: `\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

text

\part{test}

text

\end{document}`

Comment: Dear samcarter, I have to keep the "article" fashion because of other reasons.

Comment: Ok, if you want to keep the article class, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300787/36296